# Downloading content from web URL

Tags: c++, readfile, wininet

I'm trying to get data from the URL address using `WinInet.h`. Here is my simplified code:

```
LPCTSTR url = (LPCTSTR) "https://example.com"; // 2.9.1
HINTERNET connection = InternetOpenA(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
HINTERNET request = InternetOpenUrlA(connection, url, NULL, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);

char status_code[10];
DWORD info_size = 10000;
HttpQueryInfoA(request, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE, status_code, &info_size, NULL);

DWORD size;
DWORD dwRead = 0;
InternetQueryDataAvailable(request, &size, 0, 0); // size = 5

char * buffer = new char[size]; // size = 5
InternetReadFile(request, buffer, size, &dwRead);
OutputDebugString(buffer); // 1.2.3ýýýý

InternetCloseHandle(connection);
InternetCloseHandle(request);
```

It works well, but the data on the URL address is `2.9.1` but the buffer returns `2.9.1ýýýý`.

If I try to print char after char, this is the result:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    OutputDebugString(&buffer[i]);

char[0] = 2.9.1ýýýý
char[1] = .9.1ýýýý
char[2] = 9.1ýýýý
char[3] = .1ýýýý
char[4] = 1ýýýý
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: Don't forget that `char` strings in C++ are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. The *null-terminator* needs space as well (and if the `InternetReadFile` function doesn't add it for you, then you need to do it explicitly yourself). A better solution is of course to use a standard string class for your strings, like e.g. `std::string`.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but the cast in `LPCTSTR url = (LPCTSTR) "https://example.com";` is _always_ wrong. Please just remove it: `LPCTSTR url =  "https://example.com";` Infact, as you're explicitely using the 'A' version of the API just make it `LPCSTR url = https://example.com";` or even `const char* url = "https://example.com";`

Comment: @MikeVine Yes, you're right, I'll change it, thanks for the warning.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, that was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you're receiving is a C-style string, i.e. a null-character terminated array of characters. The important part here is that a string of 5 characters actually requires an array of size 6, for example:

```
"hello"
```

is made up of an array of 6 characters, `'h'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, `'o'`, `'\0'`.

`OutputDebugString` will go through the array printing the characters until it reaches a `'\0'`.

In this case you're not allocating anywhere for the terminating `'\0'` to go, so `OutputDebugString` will keep going until there happens to be a `'\0'` in memory (or until it reaches memory it's not allowed to access).

Change this bit:

```
char * buffer = new char[size]; // size = 5
InternetReadFile(request, buffer, size, &dwRead);
```

to be

```
char * buffer = new char[size + 1]; // size = 5, allocate 6 chars
InternetReadFile(request, buffer, size, &dwRead);
buffer [size] = '\0';
```

Comment: Yep, I understand now, thanks a lot for the explanation! =)